# How to achieve multitenancy in Optaplanner

Tags: optaplanner

Looking for a solution on the following scenario of task assignment . There is one tenant with  5 set of constraints (Skill, distance, , priority, duration, date) and there another tenant is having only 3 constraints( distance, skill, priority) . The problem model and 3 constraints are common for both the tenants.
Is there a way,  we can use a single instance of the planner and support both tenants on the run time based on . Can please someone guide here?

Tried to override the ConstraintProvider based on the request but no luck on this yet.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Constraint configuration](https://www.optaplanner.org/docs/optaplanner/latest/score-calculation/score-calculation.html#constraintConfiguration). This allows you to have all constraints in the single `ConstraintProvider`, but disable those you don't want triggered.

There are other solutions to this problem, but this seems to me the most straight-forward.

Comment: Let me add that if you specifically need to turn off a constraint, make its weight in the constraint configuration zero.

Comment: Thanks Lukas and Radovan for your responses. I am looking for a solution where we can achieve different constraint configuration in run time . For instance, one thread  skill constraint will be turned off, but in another thread for another the skill constraint could be active based on some pre condition  Currently need to restart the instance to reflect 
 change in constraint  configuration  and it's behavior is same across multiple threads. Something like multiple instance of ConstraintConfiguration what i am looking  for. Please let know if you have any other relevant information on this.

Comment: The solution proposed works exactly as described. Constaint configuration is part of the working solution, and therefore it can be different in every solver.